# E00114 Invalid OTS Token while creating subscription with payment nonce using accept JS in Authorize.net

Tags: c#, payment-gateway, authorize.net, recurring-billing, nonce

I am building an application using accept js and C# SDK of authorize.net. here, i am using accept js token to make a credit card payment over authorize.net and able to create transaction and customer profile successfully. but when i tried to create a subscription with customer profile id and payment profile id, i got "E00040 Record Not Found" error response.

I also tried to create subscription with another token after creating transaction but getting "E00114 Invalid OTS Token" error response.

What would cause authorize.net to return an these errors?

Looking forward for your quick response.

Answer (score 4):

I was having this problem today, although I was doing PHP on the backend instead of C#. I called into their tech support and here's what I found:

- Their production endpoints are actually pretty overloaded on server resources compared to their sandbox unfortunately, at least as of Aug, 2018. This can lead to this misleading `Invalid OTS Token` error, which can also have several other causes. The tech explained to me that if you have a submit button on the payment form that generates the token and then immediately submits the transaction, that you should add some kind of sleep call (on PHP, that's `sleep(5);`, for instance). We tried and got it to work on 4 seconds, minimum, but only intermittently. He told me if it fails after a 4 or 5 second sleep call, to reattempt that call one more time after waiting another 2 seconds, before you give up and recommend the customer call your call center or use your other support channels.
- In the sandbox, they won't care if you're not using the cert.pem file in your transactions. Not so in production -- you need to ensure you've got that loaded. You can get that file off of Github if you search on the official Authorize.Net files.

Comment: I'm using PHP and was getting this misleading error. The sleep(5) solved it for me!