# Authorize.net Error when adding new paymentProfile - code: E00114, Invalid OTS Token

Tags: node.js, authorize.net

we're trying to add a new customerPaymentProfile for an existing customerProfile. we're patterning our code on the github sample provided
https://github.com/AuthorizeNet/sample-code-node/blob/master/CustomerProfiles/create-customer-payment-profile.js

the only difference is that, we don't pass CC details to our servers. instead, we pass opaqueData from frontend. on Initial **customerProfile** creation(with a single payment profile) it works w/c is good. but if we try to add a new **paymentProfile**(using a new opaqueData) we get the error code: **E00114, Invalid OTS Token.**

the official [documentation](https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/responseCodes.html?code=E00114) regarding error code **doesn't say much**

And it seems like there's a few different cases, where it throws this error code

Using Accept.js

- https://community.developer.authorize.net/t5/Integration-and-Testing/E00114-Invalid-OTS-Token/td-p/58879
- https://community.developer.authorize.net/t5/Integration-and-Testing/E00114-Invalid-OTS-Token/td-p/59314

Our Case(node.js SDK)

- https://community.developer.authorize.net/t5/Integration-and-Testing/Error-while-adding-new-paymentProfile-quot-code-quot-quot-E00114/td-p/69872

Others

- https://community.developer.authorize.net/t5/Integration-and-Testing/Intermittent-Invalid-OTS-Token-Errors-E00114/td-p/57509
- https://community.developer.authorize.net/t5/Integration-and-Testing/E00114-Invalid-OTS-Token-error-generates-while-creating-ARB/td-p/68685

We also tried to delay the transaction at least 7 seconds, before using the opaqueData maybe to allow their systems to sync as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47578518/e00114-invalid-ots-token-while-creating-subscription-with-payment-nonce-using-ac) to receive the same error message.

Anyone ever encountered something like this before?
Any form of help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We were doing something wrong, by doing trial and error(via API) to determine if a customer exists or not. hence hitting api once or twice resulting to an invalid token (error on 2nd call)

So we tried to create a **customerProfile, w/ customerPaymentProfile** & this will throw error if customerProfile already exist(if its a duplicate email). Whats good here, is that **customerProfileId** comes with the error payload.

We though of using **customerProfileId** from error payload, to create a new payment profile for the customer, giving us some edge by reducing one DB call on our system.

The issue with our strategy though, is that **opaqueData will expire**, when we use it to create customerProfile(w/ payment profile) **even though the request failed**.

So resolution is to save customer info in our system, and check if it's a returning customer or not. If it is, then get **customerProfileId** from db, and create new  customerPaymentProfile on authorize.net

One could also create customerProfile first, w/o the customerPaymentProfile. if this transaction fails, then at least you haven't used the **opaqueData** yet and you get the **customerProfileId** w/o doing any query on your db. So when you try to create a new **customerPaymentProfile**, you won't get error code **E00114** since opaqueData isn't used yet.

lessons learned the hard way for us, but hopefully it helps someone.